# Regex matching character in substring and excluding trailing characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a single character (specifically an abbreviation for clothing size) in a Python string which can take several forms. Here are some examples of the data that I am working with:

```
'Youth Demo Short Sunset Orange S(10)'  
'Youth Demo Short Sunset Orange S-10'  
'Youth Demo Short Sunset Orange S/10'      
'Youth Demo Short Sunset Orange S'  
'S-Works Shiv S'
```

I would like to build a regex pattern that will look for either an isolated size or a size followed a non-word character and a digit and return the size. In the above data, matching the fourth example is easy with `\b(S)\b`, but that alone is not enough to keep regex from matching the `S` in `S-Works` in the fifth string. I was thinking something like the following for the first three strings:
`\bS(?=\W\d)`, but that will miss the last two strings.

Comment: You need [`r'\bS(?=$|\W\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/EYY1KZ/1)

Comment: What about `r'(?<=\s)(S)(?<![/\-\(]\d\d)|(?<=\s)(S)$'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you!